# URL and text change on scroll for each section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url

I have a fixed link that will change its text for each section on scroll. Not only the text, but also the URL should change. Has anyone an idea of how best to do that?

My Code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        var pos = $('.homeCaption').offset();
        $('.homeStage').each(function () {
            if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
                $('.homeCaption').html($(this).find('.projectDescription').text());
                return; 
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).trigger('scroll');
    });
});
```

```css
section{
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.homeCaption {
 position:fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 999;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="homeStage">
  <div class="homeStageContent">
   <p class="projectDescription" style="display: none;">Hello</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="homeStage green">
  <div class="homeStageContent">
   <p class="projectDescription" style="display: none;">Hell2o</p>
  </div>
</section>

<a class="homeCaption" href="#"></a>
```

Link to fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8zf2d2ah/3/

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: In order to change the url you can use the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423773/url-and-text-change-on-scroll-for-each-section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zf2d2ah/5/)**.

You could simply use `data-*` attributes to store the `href` for every `.projectDescription` element, like :

```
<section class="homeStage">
  <div class="homeStageContent">
    <p class="projectDescription" data-href="link1" style="display: none;">Hello</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="homeStage green">
  <div class="homeStageContent">
    <p class="projectDescription" data-href="link2" style="display: none;">Hell2o</p>
  </div>
</section>

<a class="homeCaption" href="#"></a>
```

Then in the js part get this attribute using `data()` and set the href using `prop()`, like :

```
if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
    var projectDescription = $(this).find('.projectDescription');
    $('.homeCaption').html(projectDescription.text());
    $('.homeCaption').prop('href',projectDescription.data('href'));

    return; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
    var pos = $('.homeCaption').offset();
    $('.homeStage').each(function() {
      if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
        var projectDescription = $(this).find('.projectDescription');
        $('.homeCaption').html(projectDescription.text());
        $('.homeCaption').prop('href', projectDescription.data('href'));
        return;
      }
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('scroll');
  });
});
```

```css
section {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
}

.homeCaption {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="homeStage">
  <div class="homeStageContent">
    <p class="projectDescription" data-href="link1" style="display: none;">Hello</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="homeStage green">
  <div class="homeStageContent">
    <p class="projectDescription" data-href="link2" style="display: none;">Hell2o</p>
  </div>
</section>

<a class="homeCaption" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with images instead of text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html property data to store the link that you want that section to have and then add that into the src attribute of your a elment.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        var pos = $('.homeCaption').offset();
        $('.homeStage').each(function () {
            if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
                var projDesc = $(this).find('.projectDescription');
                $('.homeCaption').html(projDesc.text());
                //This is new
                $('.homeCaption').attr('src', projDesc.data('link'));
                return; 
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).trigger('scroll');
    });
});
```

```css
section{
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.homeCaption {
 position:fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 999;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="homeStage">
  <div class="homeStageContent">
      <!-- data-link is new -->
   <p class="projectDescription" style="display: none;" data-link="www.google.com">Hello</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="homeStage green">
  <div class="homeStageContent">
   <p class="projectDescription" style="display: none;" data-link="#">Hell2o</p>
  </div>
</section>

<a class="homeCaption" href="#"></a>
```